# Automatic Login with cURL without php

Tags: scripting, login, wget, curl

I'm working in a little project using a script to do scraping.

I'm trying login in https://www.plusdede.com/login, it's a simple login with a numeric captcha. The code which is important is:

```
<div class="page-login">
    <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
    <form method="POST" action="https://www.plusdede.com/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="fU1zoQ4Ewm2xMiS3UXIZ6w3bMBBMV7Dz8xT6fLQD">

        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input id="input-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email o usuario" name="email" type="text">                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>

                        <div class="form-group captcha">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <img src="https://www.plusdede.com/captcha/flat?tkmGJHuB" alt="captcha">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group captcha">
                <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="input-captcha" for="input-captcha" class="control-label">Captcha:</label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-9"><input id="input-captcha" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe los números de la imagen" name="captcha" type="number" value=""></div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Entrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

I use the next code to my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

usuario=*******
pass=********
uagent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
encoding='accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br'
languaje='accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'
n_requests='upgrade-insecure-requests: 1'
accept='accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'
cache_control='cache-control: max-age=0'
authority='authority: www.plusdede.com' 


wget https://www.plusdede.com/login 
curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /dev/null -H "$encoding" -H "$languaje" -H "$n_requests" -H "$uagent" -H "$cache_control" -H "$authority"  https://www.plusdede.com/login

line_captcha=$(grep -i "/captcha/" login)
url_captcha=$(echo "$line_captcha" | cut -d "\"" -f 2)
wget "$url_captcha" -O captcha.png

read -p "Introducir catpcha: " cod;

line_clave=$(grep -i "form method=" login)
token=$(echo "$line_clave" | cut -d "\"" -f 14)

curl -b cjar -c cjar -H "$encoding" -H "$languaje" -H "$n_requests" -H "$uagent" -H "$cache_control" -H "$authority" --form "_token=$token" --form "email=$usuario" --form "password=$pass" --form "captcha=$cod" --location --output ./inicio.html https://www.plusdede.com/login --trace-ascii trace.txt

echo "Datos del log: "
echo "$token"
echo "$usuario"
echo "$pass"
echo "$clave"
```

I look for any error in the POST using the trace but I don't see any error, the data are correct but the request of server "inicio.html" results in an error every time.

Comment: hi, i was reading some information about the Headers, some webs block the access if yiu use cURL so you must send the "hearders" like a normal brower. For this I was writtng some new code to my script. I pick the headers using "inspect element" in chorme, next only pick the "Network" and i get the "copy as cURL" to see it. But i have a new question, one header is the cooki but i dont understand if i must sent it because i use the comands -b and -c for cooki. Is it necessary to send in a header too? Look again the post.

Comment: The whole point of [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is to prevent automated logins. Unless you have written some code to by-pass your own CAPTCHA, you are not going to be able to do this with a script.

Comment: I know but I introduce the "captcha" manualmente, i download the image, i look it and i write it. Do you think this form is impossible? I only want do 1 log and last do "scraping".